# what is the direct object & the indirect object in the sentence in my post

Tags: pronouns, indirect-objects, direct-objects

I am trying to learn about direct and indirect objects. My question is sadly very simple but I'm unsure.

In the sentence below what is the direct object & what is the indirect object?

```
She should explain it to me.
```

So I think the subject is **She**

Verb is **explain**

the direct object I believe is **it** and the indirect object **me**

Is that correct and if not why?

Comment: Usually when we refer to an "indirect object", it's in the context of [ditransitive verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb) - which can take two objects *without needing prepositions*, such as *She gave him the ball* (as opposed to *She gave the ball **to** him*, where the verb isn't really "ditransitive"). Some Anglophones would accept either or both of prepositionless  *She should explain it me* or *She should explain me it,* but these are both non-standard/dialectal usages.

Comment: Not quite: "it" is obviously direct object. But "me" is object complement of the preposition "to", not indirect object of the verb "explain". PPs don't function as objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sentences like this many linguists distinguish two categories which your teacher may or may not distinguish.

- Direct Object and Indirect Object are terms for **syntactic roles**. They are realized as noun phrases or pronouns.
- Patient and Recipient are terms for **semantic** or **thematic roles**. They usually are realized *either* as noun phrases/pronouns *or* as preposition phrases.

In your sentence *She should explain it to me*:

- *it* is both the Direct Object *and* the Patient
- *me* is the Recipient but because this role is realized as a preposition phrase *to me* it is **not** an Indirect Object.

  However, if your teacher does not recognize this distinction (and many teachers do not), you may describe *me* as the Indirect Object.

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis is almost correct, except that the verb (phrase) is "should explain".

Comment: The main verb phrase would be "should explain it to me" which includes the modal "should" and the verb phrase "explain it to me"